# What is the easiest way to boot Linux from a USB drive on Intel Mac?

Tags: boot, usb

I would like to boot an Intel Mac from Linux on an external USB drive. Right now, I have install rEFIt and use grub on the internal hard disc to boot the external drive. That seems pretty complicated. Isn't there an easier way?

In particular one that does not involved installing anything on the internal drive?

Answer (score 4):

**Apple doesn't want it to be easy!!!**

You can perhaps ask the rEFIt devs to make the specific process you want a bit easier, but I don't think you can get without having to install something to circumvent Apple-imposed restrictions.

Comment: Not so sure about this Apple imposed stuff. Actually some you can boot without rEFIt or anything installed as described in the link to the Ubuntu Forums below. But this is pretty complicated and kills graphics performance. But I have not given up hope for simpler ways. :-)